# Why does SimpleMFRC522.write not work when using RFID device on the raspberry-pi?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I just want to connect an RFID device to my raspberry. I did everything as in the tutorial (https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-rfid-rc522/) but as soon as I want to write to an RFID tag it no longer works. This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from mfrc522 import SimpleMFRC522

reader = SimpleMFRC522()

try:
        text = input('New data:')
        print("Now place your tag to write")
        reader.write(text)
        print("Written")

finally:
        GPIO.cleanup()
```

and this is the error it gave me after I press control+c (I press control+c because after I write in the data nothing happens at all):

```
Now place your tag to write
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/pi-rfid/Write.py", line 11, in <module>
    reader.write(text)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/mfrc522/SimpleMFRC522.py", line 62, in write
    id, text_in = self.write_no_block(text)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/mfrc522/SimpleMFRC522.py", line 66, in write_no_block
    (status, TagType) = self.READER.MFRC522_Request(self.READER.PICC_REQIDL)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/mfrc522/MFRC522.py", line 259, in MFRC522_Request
    (status, backData, backBits) = self.MFRC522_ToCard(self.PCD_TRANSCEIVE, TagType)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/mfrc522/MFRC522.py", line 210, in MFRC522_ToCard
    self.Write_MFRC522(self.CommandReg, command)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/mfrc522/MFRC522.py", line 159, in Write_MFRC522
    val = self.spi.xfer2([(addr << 1) & 0x7E, val])
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Comment: These posts might help: (1) https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/519993/can-rfid-read-stacked-cards/520007#520007, (2) https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/109773/how-can-rpi-spi-python-read-the-mfrc522-rfid-nfc-module